# How to save whole cmd.exe output to the specified file

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, console

Is there any way to save whole cmd.exe output to the specified file?

I can't just use the redirection operators (>, >> etc) cause the application I'm working with launches child processes and these operators doesn't affect them.

Comment: Have you seen/tried this yet? [How to quickly save what is currently shown in cmd.exe to a file](http://superuser.com/questions/411809/how-to-quickly-save-what-is-currently-shown-in-cmd-exe-to-a-file?rq=1)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Unfortunately, we need to save this information to the file in streaming manner. So we don't want to take snapshots after certain period of time, we need to redirect output constantly

Comment: If the children are normal console apps, they will inherit the standard paths from their parent, and will be subject to the same redirection. If they open their own paths for console I/O, these cannot be redirected.

Comment: @AFH "If they open their own paths for console I/O" -- what do you mean? By the way, standard way with using rediretion operators doesn't work in my case

Comment: There is STDIn, STDOut and STDErr, these are the ["standard" I/O paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) to/from the console.  Redirection works by using these; if they don't work, then that means the process is using some non-standard way to direct output to the terminal, so there's probably no 'standard' way to capture that output.  Have you checked to see if the output being put out by those sub-processes are perhaps coming through StdErr (2) instead of StdOut (1)? Perhaps you just need to (also) [redirect StdOut](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/kb/110930)...

Comment: If they use code like `fp=fopen("CON:","r")` for input (I can't immediately verify this, as I don't have a Windows C compiler immediately to hand).

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I tried both of them (`app.exe >output.txt 2>&1`)

Comment: @AFH I think you mean `fp=fopen("CON:","w")`, not the "r" mode, right?

Comment: @FrozenHeart You should edit your question and include exactly what you've tried already, and what the results were; that way we're not wasting ours and your time by suggesting things you've already tried.  Can you run the application successfully in a PowerShell command box  instead? If so, you might be able to use PowerShell's transcripts to capture the session output.

Comment: @FrozenHeart - Wrong: I was talking about redirection in general and illustrated this with opening an input path, as I stated. This avoided the need to consider the different write modes.

Comment: ConEmu is able to save output of console applications, running in its tabs, automatically.